# Noob designing Logo Help v.3

Tags: logo

Thanks all for your insights and suggestions. I've taken on board a few thing and removed a couple of other stuff. Giving more attention to the name of the company and making that stand out more than the bubbles.

This is what's come from it.

### [image: Finallogo]

Update: I've made some changes after the feedback given. Doing my best to take everything on board.The logo still feels a bit off, although I feel it's heading towards a better direction now? It's true that experience is the best teacher. Here are the changes, what do you think:

[image: Option1]

[image: Option2]

-- Thanks---

I am designing a logo for a Professional Cleaning and Organising Services start up company. The client wants something clean, sparkly and shiny so to speak. I'm finding it very hard to finalise the logo and just feel I haven't nailed it at all and I'm miles off.
I want something that represents what they want but also simple. I've managed to do a few but really looking for some guidance! Please if anyone can give me some feedback and suggestions on how to finish this project, I'd be so grateful.

[image: Logo 1]
[image: Logo 2]
[image: Logo 3]

Comment: Just a quick note- spelling for Brilliance is missing the second i- unless that was deliberate- maybe the company is led by Bri and Lance ? :)

Comment: I'm not a pro, so feel free to take my opinions with a pinch of salt… however, first, I think it's all ***way*** too busy. Second, what's a "Professional Cleaning and Organising Services". Presumably, as it's their business, they're 'professional'… who would hire amateurs? & what does 'organising' mean in this context? Then, back to the busiest logo in the world… bubbles with some [possibly mis-spelled] text buried inside… why? Your three choices seem to span from flat to skeuomorphic… OK, but even the flat is too busy.  It's all a bit 90's for me, I'm afraid.

Comment: .. there's no path for the eye to follow. it's static. I feel like, at most, you only need the 3 larges circles, positioned well.

Comment: I agree with Scott. Those additional tiny circles might feel unnecessary later.

Comment: So, the “professionals” hire an amateur for their logo?

Comment: Thank you all! The word Brillance is in French, I know brilliance in English as an i. The start up company is in France and UK so they wanted the name in French and the slogan in English. -  I do agree with you that it's very busy. They wanted a retroish vintage feel which I don't think I have accomplished very well! Tks for your feedback as I agree with you too just wasn't sure what was wrong until I've read all this. I understand now.  I agree less circles.

Answer (score 7):

1. The little star at the start of the word is is a nice touch.
2. Control the spacing between the letters. If you reduce it between some letters, the brand will look a bit more solid.
3. You are relying TOO much on the outlines. When the logo is reduced in the size you have a problem.

[image]
[image]

4. As you can see the additional text is NOT part of the logo. It is a description, it is a slogan or whatever, not a part of the logo.
5. Reduce the number of bubbles. Imagine the dots on a dice or a domino. You can easily identify from 1-6, but more dots are confusing. If you do not know how many bubbles are in your own logo, you do not know your brand.
6. Do not overlap the bubbles with the same color. As you saw on point 3 you can not use lines to differentiate the overlapping ones. Use different tones instead.

---

7. Forget your versions 2 and 3. That is an illustration, not a logo. BUT in the case of No3. The logo is now just the word Brillance, **which looks good**, over an illustration that could be part of a label.
8. So, if you make the word more solid, you do not rely on using that many bubbles, and plan them way better. Probably you can simply add just a couple of them. But you need to balance 3 elements: The word itself. The little star and the bubbles.

Comment: ,thank you so much. I will work on these changes.

Comment: Hi @Rafael, I've done some changes to the logo. Interested to see what you think tks!

Comment: @Bleuleaf in your revisions, first 5 look better. I'd select any one of them and proceed further.

Comment: From a complete layman's perspective: I love the number of bubbles. It nicely conveys that it's soap, after all. Also, the arrangement looks playful, lively and balanced, follows a rising line in Western reading direction etc.

Answer (score 7):

Simply **opinion**...

**I don't think color is your friend here.** Not *yet* anyway. I think color *may be* distracting from the *forms*.

I prefer to focus on the *form* first and deal with color later. If I focus on both color and form simultaneously, more often than not, the mark will suffer in one aspect. It's very easy to rebalance bad forms by using colors to correct any from imbalance. By avoiding colors, and focusing *only* on forms, it forces me to balance the forms first.

Since *all logos* will ultimately need to be reproduced in one color,  I want strong forms in a one color design. Ignoring color until I get forms solid is *always* beneficial for me in this respect.

If you view the basic forms *without* color.... is it appealing and strong?
<sub>(Quick trace of the font [Inkston Brush](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fenotype/inkston/brush/) since I don't own that specific typeface)</sub>

[image]

I don't know. It seems the focus is *far more* on the large circle than anything else. And when it's reduced....

[image]

The type simply gets lost completely. Not good.

In terms of **eye movement**.. what you've current got pushes hard to the right... English, and I assume French, are read left to right, so a right direction becomes inherent and the *best* marks/logos work to incorporate that movement and to try and push the eye back to the left.

If you merely look at how reversing the position of the smaller circles alters eye movement, there may be some improvement there....

[image]

And lastly... I don't know why you need that large background circle. I don't think it's providing any dynamic visual appeal. I, personally, would tend to *move away* from having that large background circle (bubble) and explore other implementations while retaining the "bubble" concept -- since that *is a good concept* to try and incorporate.

<sub>(Again, type is merely traced here. It's not great.)</sub>

[image] [image]

Using the dot of the `i` as a bubble is, by no means, an "Earth-shattering", innovative, idea. You may be able to do something far more creative if you start thinking of *not* using big circles. `:)` this was a 10 minute rework to show *possibilities*, not to create an actual mark for use.

The swash along the bottom is *not* random. It's *specifically* used to push the eye back to the left. With this, although the art was done really fast and is unrefined, it creates a "circle" movement for the eye... read the word, the swash pulls the eye to the left, the bubbles pull the eye up.. read the word.. repeat.

[image]

---

<sub>(Just a personal demand I place on myself... *never* create a logo with a font so basic that *anyone* can merely install the font and pick it from a font menu to duplicate the logo. *Always* do something more to any type in a logo. This is why I've manually added highlights to the type above. They could be done with a great deal more care and precision, but you get the idea. The little star on the tail of the B is a nice touch and along these lines. It could be pushed a bit more though. -- Again, that's merely a *personal* demand I place upon myself I'm not stating you must or should do any such thing. )</sub>

Comment: Last one is good suggestion keeping in mind OP needs circles

Comment: I'm curious about the personal demand. Did you write more on why you're doing that and how it affects your results somewhere? If you have a short blogpost or a tweet chain or something, it sounds like an interesting 5min read :)

Comment: @lucidbrot Sorry No. No real additional writing for a link. It's just a personal mantra "good enough isn't". I consider myself a "craftsman" and to that end, try to go above and beyond in my work whenever possible. It carries through to all areas of work... never use a stock photo without doing *something* to improve it....  Never use tracing apps to create vector artwork.... etc.

Answer (score 1):

Nice work! I love the white line from #1, makes the word "Brilliance" pop off the background a bit better. I would add that to the other designs. I prefer the bubble from #2 best, with #3 also really nice. But #3 probably needs a lighter background so the bubble pops out from it more: you want the company name to really jump out at the viewer. With all of these I would look to deliver a monochrome/small size logo that prints well on black and white or at small sizes. Maybe switch the font at the bottom of #3 to a thicker weight if you went with that one for this.

Comment: I really appreciate you feed back. I will apply your suggestions and keep working on the logo.

Comment: Hi, @copilot I've made some changes to logo, decided to work on the 1st, added the bubble from the 2nd to the 1st. the 3rd one I've left out. I did a few variations. Lemme know what you think. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

Opinions:

The original idea of bubbles was fine. The original 1st version was simple enough, the original 2nd and 3rd versions are too complex for this purpose, no matter how fine drawings they are.

The problem in the original 1st version is the visibility of the business name. It should be the biggest item. The additional slogan can be smaller, but the business name should conduct the perception. An example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not a pro just giving my opinion,to me at the first glance, it looks like a car wash logo. also if they try to embroider logos with outline , it will be nightmare to keep the two colors register.
Imagine everything needs to fit in 3.5"-4" wide area and still be legible.

Comment: Hi I see what you mean. I know what to do now...next time I'll decline and leave it to the pros! ha! Definitely been a challenge and not my forte. Thanks for your insight. never even thought about the embroidery issue.

Comment: I didn't mean to discourage you, it is just an opinion.

Comment: Ohh you haven't!! I was just joking. I can't give up now, I'm gonna keep chipping away at it. I really appreciate any kind of opinion, insights, suggestions and all that. :-)